# Computer restarts when windows 7 installation is tried to boot [video]

Tags: windows, linux, boot, reboot

Here is Video [Link](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5WgUIsNlCx8) of my problem

It boots well into Windows installation, but then something happens and computer restarts. USB with Windows is OK. It doesn't happen on another computer. When booting Linux it works well, there is Ubuntu 10.04 installed as I can't install windows. Windows were installed and worked fine on the same computer before.

What could be wrong, how can I install Windows ?

Comment: That didn't look like Windows Setup to me. Are you trying to install Windows onto the computer from the USB drive? Or are you trying to boot Windows from the USB drive which you have installed on?

Comment: In first few seconds it's linux ubuntu running, then I reboot and plug in USB and try to install windows 7 from the USB.